# MVC Default Edit View increments the id property of my model? Can't figure out why. .

Tags: entity-framework, debugging, model-view-controller

I'm trying to learn web development, and I bet that this is a simple problem and that I'm overlooking something obvious.

In my default crud edit controller (generated using the MVC framework) I retrieve my model from a localDB instance using my EntityFramework's dbContext. That is sent to the View. In the debugger just before the controller call to `return View(model)` I can see that the Id is set to 2.

When the [post] edit controller is fired I see that the identity property is 3. I wanted to figure out why so I changed the View to display my Id property and I see that it is 3 as soon as I render the page. Last time I saw it the property was 2, now it is 3.

I don't know how to hook into any logic that would happen between the time I send off my model and when when the view is rendered.

Can anyone help me learn how to debug this so that I can figure out why my Id property is incremented when I pass the model into the view?

Comment: Well, you could look at the message sent to the browser but that obviously says `3`, unless there is some sneaky javascript running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Posting here for anyone else that comes across my problem.

I tried dumping the whole model out without using any of the htmlhelper methods. (In my case I am uinging: `Html.HiddenFor` helper)  When I did this I saw that the value in the model was what I expected it to be. So I began investigating why the helper methods might be broken. Google worked for me here :)

Turns out, when the helper methods run they first check the `ModelState` dictionary for the desired value. In my case I was looking for a value that was in my model object as well as the ModelState dictionary, because the name was very common: Id.

To fix the issue before I call `return View(model)` I call `ModelState.Clear()` in order to make sure there are no values in the dictionary that are in conflict. Doing this causes my page to be rendered correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how EntityFramework works but I have worked with CakePHP. My advice is like this:

1. Usually PHP frameworks have debug mode which you can set in the configuration file (turn it on or off). Usually stack of operation executed is also displayed in debug mode or there is a simple way to do that. There's also for example in CakePHP exist function debug($yourVariable); try to search for sth. similar
2. It seams like not the edit happens but new row is inserted to the database. Check your database for this. I recommend to debug the id of the column being passed for edit action and check if there's the same id in the database first of all.

Hope something helps.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the debug mode. I've started looking into similar options for Asp.net and MVC